# Do Kafka consumers consume messages from a topic partition by partition?

Tags: apache-kafka

Suppose I have 3 partitions in a topic and I connect a consumer to consume messages from this topic. Will the consumer consume all the messages from one partition, then the next, then the final one, or could the consumer consume from different partitions in a random manner?

Answer (score 0):

Ordering across partitions is never guaranteed from Kafka consumers. Only within a partition, will you consume increasing offsets.

Some Kafka clients have the concept of a PartitionAssignor, so it is not "random". If a client is assigned multiple partitions, it can poll from all of them, in parallel, where the only guarantee is that offsets are increasing. You can collect all polled records into some mapping from partition number to a sorted linked-list, if you wish, then iterate in the order you describe, but this comes at the cost of processing speed (e.g. will cause higher consumer lag).